# sed command to locate a string containing alphanumeric characters and spaces and perform positional replacement in that string

Tags: sed

i have a file with below line

```
aadz(mdb awetyi),Lll,Dweuio: mdb 1:00.0  ARF = 0x000000006e1d9000
```

i want to locate `ARF = 0x000000006e1d9000` and perform positional replacement of certain positions like 12,13,14 etc with x. the final result should look like

```
aadz(mdb awetyi),Lll,Dweuio: mdb 1:00.0  ARF = 0x000000006xxx000
```

i tried this command

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.\{12\}\)./\1x/' -e  's/\(.\{13\}\)./\1x/'  -e  's/\(.\{74\}\)./\1x/' file
```

but it replaces the characters from start of the line containing the text which is not desired
I'm unable to locate only `ARF = 0x000000006xxx000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following command

```bash
sed -E 's/(ARF = .{11}).{3}/\1xxx/g' file
```

It matches `ARF =` , 11 following symbols and replaces following three symbols with `xxx`

Option `-i` is not included in example: first test to see that replacement is happening like you want.